# Android Firebase notification (Unknown Source) error

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working to add Firebase notifications to my Android application. I did all the firebase-android required.

build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.grudle (app):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But it's showing a lot of missing-Unknown source

```
02-20 18:57:56.634 925-925/com.sarazeef.teaoria E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.sarazeef.teaoria, PID: 925
                                                                  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzaaj()Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/data/com.sarazeef.teaoria/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-iid-10.2.0_d53622db8f96b7ec4a26866e04f3b40994f5004d-classes.dex)
                                                                      at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzF(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4128)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1924)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I need to solution pls .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that you're using different versions of Firebase SDK for firebase-core and firebase-messaging - maybe this is the issue?
Also, it's a good practice to move the dependency versions to a common place so that you can update the version once for all - https://medium.com/@ivan_m/use-variables-to-manage-gradle-android-dependencies-library-version-numbers-92f0e362a2fc#.qsxuygtl7 .